# Django Rest Framework and url shortcuts

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a url:

```
    path('reservations/',
        views.ReservationViewSet.as_view(dict(get='list', post='create')),
        name='reservations'),
```

so I will call it like: `reservations?restaraunt=3`

and I want to have a shortcut for it:

```
    path('restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/reservations/',
        views.RestaurantReservationsForwardView.as_view(),
        name='restaurant-reservations'),
```

which I gonna call like `restaurants/3/reservations`

so, I have two views:

```
class ReservationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Reservation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ReservationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        restaurant_id = self.request.query_params.get('restaurant', None)
        if restaurant_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(restaurant=restaurant_id)
        return queryset

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['restaurant'] = request.query_params.get('restaurant')
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)


class RestaurantReservationsForwardView(View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.GET = request.GET.copy()
        request.GET['restaurant'] = kwargs.get('restaurant_id')
        return ReservationViewSet.as_view(dict(get='list', post='create'))(request)
```

It works but I fill like inventing the will. Also the I duplicate the dict which I puth inside `as_view` in dispatch

What is the intended way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case is extract the functionality for fetching `restaurant_id` and extract it from `request.query_params` or `kwargs`. With this in mind, you'll have only the viewset and just register it in 2 different URLs:

> `views.py`

```
class ReservationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Reservation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ReservationSerializer

    def get_restaurant_id(self):
        restaurant_id = self.request.query_params.get('restaurant')
        # ?restaurant=

        if not restaurant_id:
            restaurant_id = self.kwargs.get('restaurant_id')
            # /restaurants/:restaurant_id

        return restaurant_id

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        restaurant_id = self.get_restaurant_id()
        # ___________________^
        if restaurant_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(restaurant=restaurant_id)
        return queryset

    ...
```

> And then in `urls.py`

```
path('restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/reservations/',
    views.ReservationViewSet.as_view(),
    name='restaurant-reservations'),
```